# influence iPhone website shortcut

Tags: ios, iphone, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing a MobileApp View with Sencha Touch 2 for our website. I also added the website as home screen shortcut on my iPhone.

Is there any to manipulate the opening options of the website in a iPhone homescreen shortcut?

My problem is, if i open the website by clicking on the shortcut, the page is every time loaded. My problem is, if the "website shortcut app" is opened in the background, it shouldn't refresh. So it hasn't the same behaviour like in the Safari mobile browser.

Is there any way to manipulate this behaviour? Programmatically or in the iPhone settings?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the same behaviour like in the Safari mobile browser. Any bookmark you save to the home screen, whether it's web app enabled or not, will refresh on opening.

One work around is to use Sencha Touch's support for routing. Whenever a new route in the app is opened, save that route in localstorage as "last_route" or something like that. On each load of the app you could then call controller.redirectTo(localStorage.getItem("last_route")); to go straight back to the last route (and therefore view) that the user accessed.

Have a read of Sencha's routing guide if you're not familiar with it:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/history_support